# Positive Definiteness Constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra

I want to add a constraint to a convex program, to guarantee some matrix $A$ to be positive semidefinite.
How should I do it?

The library I am working with can cope with linear/ quadratic inequalities only.

By definition, $A$ is positive semidefinite iff $\forall x \in \mathbb C^n : x^T A x \geq 0$, but this is a set of inifinitely many constraints. So, my question is: how can I formulate it using a finitely many set of contraints and using linear/ quadratic inequalities only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the constraint "$A$ is positive semidefinite". This is a convex constraint since the positive semidefinite matrices form a convex cone.

Comment: If your question is about a particular convex programming library, then it's probably out of scope here.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you are asking. Community votes, please: unclear?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Hello. Do you know if any reference book about solving optimization with positive definite constraints? Thanks!

Comment: There's this new monograph: https://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Convex-Optimization-Nisheeth-Vishnoi/dp/1108741770

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite if and only if there exists a matrix $V$ such that $$A = V^\top V.$$
So, you can use the entries of $V$ as your unknowns, and express each entry of $A$ as a quadratic function of the unknowns.  Whenever you want to use $A$, instead rewrite that equation in terms of the entries of $V$.